# Count down timer

Tags: iphone, timer, uilabel

I need a count down timer starting from 5 min.

Comment: ..3..2..1 Now! ....

Comment: @Mitch - Your solution only counts down from 3.

Comment: Damn I was going to post that comment !!!!

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos : That's why it's a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here : http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7590-touch-event-countdown-timer.html or here http://www.servin.com/iphone/iPhone-Timers-and-Animated-Views.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), particularly the method:

`+timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`

If you want someone to write you an application, feel free to get in touch with me and I'll quote you a price on the source code.